# Read tabular file with multiple headers and values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read/stream a file which has multiple rows in between with headers:

- It has one file header and corresponding to this only one row as file record.
- And then it will have one/more batch headers each having one/more batch records (with values).
- And then file batch tailer (has only one record for value).
- And then file trailer (has only one record for value)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Report_name       ,Report_Date,         ,     
Report 4th grade  , 3/24/2022 ,         ,     
Section           , Name      , Subject ,Score
A                 , Mark      , English ,85   
A                 , Jack      , Maths   , 95  
Section           , Total     ,         ,     
A                 , 180       ,         ,     
Section           , Name      , Subject ,Score
B                 , John      , English , 95  
B                 , Carter    , Maths   , 86  
Section           , Total     ,         ,     
B                 , 181       ,         ,     
Grade             , Total     ,         ,     
4th               , 361       ,         ,     
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to read the data from the file, preferably in dict/json format and then compare data with another datastore (by pulling data).

first read: {{Report_name,Report 4th grade}, {Report_Date,3/24/2022}}

second read : {{Section,A},{Name, Mark},{Subject, English},{Score, 85}}
Third read : {{Section,A},{Name, Jack},{Subject, Maths},{Score, 95}}

I thought I might be able to use `csv.DictReader`, but it's helpful only if the file has only one header and subsequent rows as values.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your expected output?

Comment: @itprorh66 I update the question, and to answer to your question: want to compare this data with data from database

Comment: That doesn't appear to be CSV.

Comment: I am confused, it he data table shown your desired output?  If, yes what does the input look like?  If the table shown is your input, what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @mkrieger1 tried to make it more csv look alike.

Comment: @itprorh66 i just want to get the (key,val) from this file where key is from header, and val from respective data under the relevant header
like this:
 in the first read: {{Report_name,Report 4th grade}, {Report_Date,3/24/2022}

and in the second read : {{Section,A},{Name, Mark},{Subject, English},{Score, 85}

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure how you want to handle the Total line but the following approach creates a Pandas DataFrame from your input data, from which you can convert to a csv using the `df.to_csv()` function and you can get statistics such as toal scores as well as median, high and low using pandas group_by functions.  So here is the approach I would use:
Given input file whose location is denoted by variable `datafile` of form:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Report_name       ,Report_Date,         ,     
Report 4th grade  , 3/24/2022 ,         ,     
Section           , Name      , Subject ,Score
A                 , Mark      , English ,85   
A                 , Jack      , Maths   , 95  
Section           , Total     ,         ,     
A                 , 180       ,         ,     
Section           , Name      , Subject ,Score
B                 , John      , English , 95  
B                 , Carter    , Maths   , 86  
Section           , Total     ,         ,     
B                 , 181       ,         ,     
Grade             , Total     ,         ,     
4th               , 361       ,         ,     
-------------------------------------------------------------  

import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# Function to read data into a list of lists:
def readText(fpth: str) -> list:
    lines = []
    with open(fpth, 'r') as records:
        for rec in records:
            # strip the newline character from the line
            itm = rec.strip().split(',')
            if len(itm) >= 2:  # skip leading & trailing demarc lines
                lines.append(itm)  
    return  lines

def processFile(fdata: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    recDict = defaultdict(list)
    rept_Title = fdata[1][0].strip()
    rept_Date = fdata[1][1]
    id = 3
    while id < len(fdata):
        if fdata[id][0].strip() != 'Section' and fdata[id][0].strip() != 'Grade':
            recDict["Report"].append(rept_Title)
            recDict['Date'].append(rept_Date)
            recDict['Section'].append(fdata[id][0].strip())
            recDict['Name'].append(fdata[id][1].strip())
            recDict['Subject'].append(fdata[id][2].strip())
            recDict['Score'].append(fdata[id][3].strip())
        elif  fdata[id][0].strip() == 'Grade':
            grde_list = [fdata[id+1][0].strip()] * len(recDict["Name"])
            recDict['Grade'].extend(grde_list)
            id += 1
        elif fdata[id][0].strip() == 'Section' and fdata[id][1].strip() == 'Total':
            id += 1
        id +=1
    return pd.DataFrame(recDict)
```

Executing `processFile(readText(datafile))`, yields the dataframe:

```
         Report         Date    Section Name    Subject Score   Grade
0   Report 4th grade    3/24/2022   A   Mark    English  85     4th
1   Report 4th grade    3/24/2022   A   Jack    Maths    95     4th
2   Report 4th grade    3/24/2022   B   John    English  95     4th
3   Report 4th grade    3/24/2022   B   Carter  Maths    86     4th
```